# Adding into each existing object within JSON array new values from file/variable/command using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have json like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "2"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "3"
    } 
]
```

I call some "sizes.sh" that give me result:

```
10
20
30
```

How can I update my original json with these results, so it will look:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "size": 10
    }, 
    {
        "id": "2",
        "size": 20

    }, 
    {
        "id": "3",
        "size": 30

    }
]
```

Comment: Please specify how to deal with edge cases, e.g. what if the numbers of items don't line up?

Comment: there are no edge cases in my case... sizes.sh always returns same number of results according to json's number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
./sizes.sh | jq '[., [{size: inputs}]] | transpose | map(add)' file.json -
```

Comment: thanks! what "-' means in the end?

Comment: @Dima It means the standard input. Without it jq won't read the output of `./sizes.sh`.

Comment: understood! what if i want "feed" sizes.sh results from variable where i store it prior?

Comment: @Dima `echo "$sizes" | jq ...`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I update my original json

`jq` cannot "update" a file, you'll have to let the shell do it. Assuming a POSIX shell, you could redirect the output to a temporary file using `>`, and overwrite the original on success using `mv -f`:

```bash
./sizes.sh |
jq -Rn --slurpfile in original.json > temp.json \
  '$in + [[{size: inputs}]] | transpose | map(add)' &&
mv -f temp.json original.json
```